Debezium Columns with user defined types not available
After configuring debezium to capture events from my table T1 whenever I change a row I get a warning like the following

WARN Column 'myCol1' available in capture table not found among source table columns
(io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerChangeTablePointer)

Which causes that the data from those fields are not included inside the Kafka topic.
Said columns are using User-Defined data types like CString:varchar(30)
I've tried using a custom converter with the following method
public class CustomSqlTypeConverter  implements CustomConverter<SchemaBuilder, RelationalColumn> {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomSqlTypeConverter.class);


    @Override
    public void configure(Properties props) {

    }

    @Override
    public void converterFor(RelationalColumn column, ConverterRegistration<SchemaBuilder> registration) {
        String columnType = column.typeName().toUpperCase();
        switch (columnType) {
            case "NSTRING":
            case "CSTRING":
            case "QSTRINGDT":
            case "TCODE":
            case "TINFO":
            case "TINFO_U":
                registration.register(SchemaBuilder.string().optional(), rs -> rs.toString());
                LOGGER.info("Mapped SQL type CONTRACTNAME to String.");
                break;

        

            default:
                LOGGER.debug("No custom mapping for type: {}", columnType);
        }
       
    
        
    }


}

Also I have tried to explicitly listed the columns in the connector configuration
 "column.include.list": "dbo.table1.(pkCol|myCol1|myCol2)


I'm using SQL Server 2017 and Debezium 3.0.2 Final

What version of sql-server and debezium are you using?

@BartMcEndree added to the post

registration.register(SchemaBuilder.string().optional(), rs -> rs.toString()); wouldn't this map same name multiple times?

no, what that does is calling toString to the value of the column
